# Hardware controller for Laptop in Linux

Tags: nvidia, hardware, laptop, gpu, asus

I have a Asus gaming laptop and I want to format and use it with Linux (I'm new user) but there is some problem:
The main one is Asus doesn't have Armoury Crate and without some kinda of controller (for fan speed, disabling nvidia gpu, keyboard light and...) it's not a pleasant experience, the only thing that I found is asusctrl but it can't control everything and only supports Fedora and G-Helper (Better than Armoury Crate it self) won't Support Linux

Is there any suggestion?

PS: the best experience I had with couple of Distros that I tested was Pop_OS! because of the nvidia driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint, but I highly doubt that there is an all-in-one app to control everything. You will most likely have to cobble together a bunch of different programs for different pieces of hardware.

For the keyboard RGB, [OpenRGB](https://openrgb.org/devices_0.9.html) is available on Linux and seems to have decent support for asus hardware.

For fan speed and GPU switching, try taking a look at this [archwiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/ASUS). Keep in mind that this article is written with Arch linux in mind, but most of what it says should be applicable to any distro.

What I can tell you is that setting up this kind of thing definitely won't be a plug-and-play experience, especially for a novice user. We often joke that getting nvidia drivers to work requires bringing a fragment of your sanity as sacrifice to Jensen; this is doubly true for laptops.

Finally, if there is something that you absolutely cannot find a software controller for, you may have to dual-boot Linux and Windows, and just switch into windows and use Armoury Crate. If the device is actually using an internal USB connection, it might also be possible to run Windows in a virtual machine (I recommend qemu) and temporarily route the device into the VM to change settings.

EDIT: If you do decide to dual boot, please note that Linux (and windows) has a feature called Hibernate which basically allows you to turn off your computer without losing your work. It basically saves your RAM to disk before turning off. It's very useful if you do end up switching operating system often, or going into BIOS to change settings on the fly. For hibernate to work, you need to set the size of your swapfile or swap partition to be at least as large as your RAM when installing Linux (two times the size of your RAM is the recommended amount).

Comment: It's interesting to me why so many awesome devs in Linux community's take the time to create many things that already exist in some other form like so many distros but not making 1 or 2 solid OS

Comment: I've heard someone say that asking why a developer is making yet another new distro is like asking why a musician is writing yet another song about love...